# How to ensure atomic read-then-write w/ SQLAlchemy in a multithread web service

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I use a simple table in SQL Server as a document store, for the sake of simplicity let's assume it's a two-column table (doc_name, doc_content) and the doc_content should always be valid JSON string.

The web service provides a PATCH method which allows user to update specific key/value pairs in the JSON string, the URL is used for the doc_name and request body contains JSON Patch which specified what to do with the content of the document. So each PATCH action involves reading the JSON document from the database, modifying it and saving it again in the database.

I'm using `scoped_session` from SQLAlchemy to help manage sessions in multiple threads:

```
session_factory = sessionmaker()
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://{}/{}?driver=SQL+Server'.format(db_server, db_name))
Session.configure(bind=engine)
```

A simplified version of the code to patch the document looks like this:

```
@api.route('/', methods=['PATCH'])
def patch():
    doc = Session.query(MyDoc).one()
    # cast string stored in the database to an object
    doc_obj = json.loads(doc.value)

    # apply patch to the doc object
    patch = request.get_data(as_text=True)
    patch.apply(doc_obj)

    # cast the doc object back to json and save it
    doc.value = json.dumps(doc_obj)
    Session.merge(doc)
    Session.commit()
```

My problem is then how to make `patch` works in a multithread environment, I know `scoped_session` is local to each thread and that's great, but how do I ensure that read-then-write actions in `scoped_session` are atomic? I don't want to see the case where sessions from two separate threads simultaneously read the same document and each apply a patch to their own copies, which will lead to one of the patches being lost forever when they each save their own result back to the database.

I read a few blogs on setting isolation level, but that doesn't seem to meet my need, it can't block a 'read' by reading something as far as I understand. I guess I can manually add a `lock` to `patch` method but that might not be the best way of resolving this

Thanks for the help!.

Comment: If you want to read data from a DB, and be sure nobody's updating the data before you update them, use a DB transaction and `select for update` on the records you want to update. If a conflicting update occurs in a parallel thread, the first thread to commit would make the update, and the other thread will get an error and will roll back the changes.

Comment: @9000 thanks, I'll give that a try